# How can I log directly into Gmail when I am also signed into Google Apps?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-account, url, google-multi-login

**Background:**

- I have one Gmail account and two Google Apps e-mail accounts that I use on a regular basis:

  - <my.name@gmail.com>
  - <myaddress@teaching-job.edu>
  - <my.name@consulting-job.com>
- On my personal computer, all three accounts are kept "signed in" concurrently so that I can access any of the three inboxes at any time without having to log in repeatedly.

  - If I browse to https://mail.google.com/a/teaching-job.edu/ or https://mail.teaching-job.edu/, Gmail takes me directly to the inbox for <myaddress@teaching-job.edu>.
  - If I browse to https://mail.google.com/a/consulting-job.com/ or https://mail.consulting-job.com/, Gmail takes me directly to the inbox for <my.name@consulting-job.com>
  - If I browse to https://mail.google.com/ or https://www.gmail.com/, Gmail does *not* take me directly to the inbox for <my.name@gmail.com>. Instead, it takes me to one of my Google Apps accounts.
  - Browsing to https://mail.google.com/a/gmail.com/ yields an error: "Sorry, you've reached a login page for a domain that isn't using Google Apps."

**Question:**

- Assuming that I am signed into all three accounts concurrently, is there a URL that will *always* bring me directly to the inbox for <my.name@gmail.com>, even if I have used one of the other accounts more recently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that when using multiple sign-in, the *first* account that one signs into is forevermore the "default account" for that browser session. This applies to all Google Apps features: not just logins to https://mail.google.com/, but also things like OpenID sign-ins.

The solution was simply to sign out, log into the gmail.com account first, and then log into the Google Apps accounts.

Comment: Although this solves my problem, this unfortunately won't help someone who has multiple addresses @gmail.com and wants a URL to open each inbox. I'm still curious as to whether there's a way to build a URL that will always default to a specific Gmail address.

Comment: What about https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/, https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/ and so forth? This might work for several Gmail addresses, *if* you know (or can control) in which order you signed in to them.

Answer (score -2):

Make use of the Account chooser.

[Account chooser](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=14129&answer=1691641)

**UPDATE:** I've created a Gmail account besides my Google Apps accounts. Within the e-mail application (or wathever google apps programm) you can switch to other accounts easily, when using the account chooser. This in essence enables you to directly log on to different e-mail accounts.

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit? _Why_ does this solve the OP's issue?

Comment: I didn't verify the Gmail vs. Google Apps usage. However, some blogs kept on usage the Gmail reference to their solution. That's why I blundly/boldy added my answer.