# Google multiple sign-in fails to switch users!

Tags: gmail, google-account

I'm in Gmail with 3 Google accounts signed-in.  When I choose to switch to a different user account from the drop-down menu in the upper right of Gmail, it pops open a new Gmail window for the same user as before.  What gives?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: Try using the following answer: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/36090/29140

Answer (score 1):

This seems to happen from time to time in my experience (4 accounts), especially if I try to log into two accounts at once from the same domain (examples: user1@mydomain.com and user2@mydomain.com)

Just restarting the browser works much of the time.

If not, logging out and starting over usually works. Starting over = logging into each account again.

Rare cases I have to log out and wait 30 minutes to try again.

To log into another account from the same domain use the generic GMail login screen and enter the full email address as the user id.

Comment: Logging out and then back in did 'work' for me as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

This still happens to me all the time. I find that I need to do the following:

1. Switch to the account I want to sign in to.
2. When the password screen comes up I enter the WRONG password and submit the page.(I'm assumming it just cleared the cookies)
3. Now enter the correct password and it should work.

It then takes me to the correct account. If I just enter the correct password it always takes me to the wrong account.

Comment: This doesn't work for me because when I choose to sign in with a different account, then choose UserB, it loads the login page for UserA again. Grr. Logging out and then back in did 'work' as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I meet same problem many times and trust its authorisation scripts problem. Google try to make accounts switching easy - just this brings some small problems with so many services they offering using same authorisation data.

---

I use iGoogle which loads for specific account and sometimes it ask me to re-enter account password to be able to bring me mail messages inside iGoogle. In other words to access my iGoogle account the password is ok, but NOT to access the same account mail messages. Authorisation scripts used in iGoogle and on Gmail gadget on it are different authorising on different ways - but trust they write in same variables in my browser to keep my login data for all further cases when account authorisation will be required.

Every account have own number in the list of all available accounts inside current browser.
The primary account have id 0, then all other have own number depending of the order of signups. When you switch google accounts the account id is passed through URL: 
`https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/`
Changing the number from 0 to 1, 2, 3 allows you to easy switch between accounts (no pop-up).

If this not works the sign-out is the only available option, which must clear all authorisation problems.